# Are the expressions "to put it mildly" and "to say the least" always interchangeable?

Tags: expressions, differences

As we know, the expressions "to put it mildly" and "to say the least" are used to avoid describing something in the strongest way possible. But I wonder if there is a subtle difference between the two.

> The dinner was not tasty, **to say the least**.
>
> The movie contains some scenes that are, **to put it mildly**, rather
> difficult to watch.

Comment: I've no references to back this, but to my ears, 'to say the least' sounds more formal and perhaps less emotionally charged , less suggestive of exasperation. My impressions could be down to the contexts I've heard 'to put it mildly' in, not a huge sample size.

Comment: There's a difference in the literal meaning between the two: "to say the least" means you could say more (e.g. rant at greater length), while "to put it mildly" means you could use stronger language instead (replacing your existing euphemistic language). "To say the least" can sound like you're omitting something (e.g. not only was dinner not tasty but there was a massive argument), which isn't really a connotation of "to put it mildly".

Comment: In practice, both are formal and it doesn't matter which one you use.